# Jquery Outerhtml add extra unwanted style

Tags: jquery, outerhtml

i have the following code to get the html code when i clicked on a element, for e.g. < p>

```
$('#button').click(function(){
     var a = $(this).wrap('<div></div>').parent().html(); 
     alert(a);
});
```

when a button is clicked, i want to get the content of the element i am clicking.

For first click, i am able to get exactly what i wanted. However when i clicked the 2nd time, i realize that some extra style is added to the element.

Example: style="background-color:transparent;border-top-width:0 etc"

Why is this happening? Will appreciate any enlightenment!

Comment: Doesn't see to happen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JMC_Creative/XP7uF/).

Comment: but your code wrap the clicked item with multi level of divs, isn't a problem?

Comment: Hi, i updated http://jsfiddle.net/XP7uF/7/ basically it happens. i am trying to click on an element in an iframe. appreciate any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to wrap your element in a div, then find your element's parent (the div) and retrieve the HTML out of that. You can simply grab the HTML right out of your element, like this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
     alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Or you could do this (more jQuery-ish):

```
$('#button').click(function(){
     alert($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Well, i did this because i need to get the code of the element that i am clicking also. (not just the code inside).

e.g. 

<p> THis is my content</p>

When i click on <P> element, i need to get the full <p> This is my content</p>.

Using $(this).html() will only get "this is my content"

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. Issue occurs because i added the style via jquery. Logic design issue. Thanks all for the help!